# Trying to fit a lightbox image + caption in screen

Tags: jquery, css, image, lightbox

Got a lightbox on my site, but large images fit to screen height, obscuring the caption underneath.  I'd love ideally for the lightbox to leave about 20px top and bottom.

Thanks anyone, for the help.

CSS:

```
#lightbox{
 background-color:#ffffff;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size:12pt;
 }

#lightboxDetails{
 font-size: 0.8em;
 } 

#lightboxCaption{ 
  float: left; padding:5px; 
}

#keyboardMsg {
  float: left; 
  clear:both;
  margin:10px 0 10px 0;
  padding:0 0px 0 5px;
}

#closeButton{ 
top: 5px; right: 5px; 
  display:none;
}

#lightbox img{ 
  border: none; 
  clear: both;
}

#overlay img{ border: none; }

#overlay{ 
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 }

* html #overlay{
 background-color: #333;
 background-color: transparent;
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-IuRWmtxsbLg/TlDQr1esv2I/AAAAAAAABTw/FiWsnpa0Gcw/s320/overlay.png", sizingMethod="scale");
 }

#overlay img { 
  border: none; 
}

#overlay { 
  background-image: url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-B6R41EjOobU/TrZkBklKcrI/AAAAAAAAEk8/dBzVL1ojJSY/s1600/overlay.png); 
}

* html #overlay{
 background-color: #333;
 background-color: transparent;
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-IuRWmtxsbLg/TlDQr1esv2I/AAAAAAAABTw/FiWsnpa0Gcw/s320/overlay.png", sizingMethod="scale");
 }
```

JS:

```
/*
        Lightbox JS: Fullsize Image Overlays 
        by Lokesh Dhakar - http://www.huddletogether.com

        For more information on this script, visit:
        http://huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox/

        Script featured on Dynamic Drive code library Jan 24th, 06':
        http://www.dynamicdrive.com

        Licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution 2.5 License - http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.5/
        (basically, do anything you want, just leave my name and link)

        Table of Contents
        -----------------
        Configuration

        Functions
        - getPageScroll()
        - getPageSize()
        - pause()
        - getKey()
        - listenKey()
        - showLightbox()
        - hideLightbox()
        - initLightbox()
        - addLoadEvent()

        Function Calls
        - addLoadEvent(initLightbox)

*/



//
// Configuration
//

// If you would like to use a custom loading image or close button reference them in the next two lines.
var loadingImage = 'http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-7uyXRys2Ccg/TlDQrr-E84I/AAAAAAAABTo/n11es5Xv_gQ/s1600/loading.gif';               
var closeButton = 'http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-S8A4KmUkK-A/TlDQraUx5wI/AAAAAAAABTg/DojRZ4VPmp4/s320/close.gif';           





//
// getPageScroll()
// Returns array with x,y page scroll values.
// Core code from - quirksmode.org
//
function getPageScroll(){

        var yScroll;

        if (self.pageYOffset) {
                yScroll = self.pageYOffset;
        } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop){      // Explorer 6 Strict
                yScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        } else if (document.body) {// all other Explorers
                yScroll = document.body.scrollTop;
        }

        arrayPageScroll = new Array('',yScroll) 
        return arrayPageScroll;
}



//
// getPageSize()
// Returns array with page width, height and window width, height
// Core code from - quirksmode.org
// Edit for Firefox by pHaez
//
function getPageSize(){

        var xScroll, yScroll;

        if (window.innerHeight && window.scrollMaxY) {  
                xScroll = document.body.scrollWidth;
                yScroll = window.innerHeight + window.scrollMaxY;
        } else if (document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.offsetHeight){ // all but Explorer Mac
                xScroll = document.body.scrollWidth;
                yScroll = document.body.scrollHeight;
        } else { // Explorer Mac...would also work in Explorer 6 Strict, Mozilla and Safari
                xScroll = document.body.offsetWidth;
                yScroll = document.body.offsetHeight;
        }

        var windowWidth, windowHeight;
        if (self.innerHeight) { // all except Explorer
                windowWidth = self.innerWidth;
                windowHeight = self.innerHeight;
        } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight) { // Explorer 6 Strict Mode
                windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
                windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        } else if (document.body) { // other Explorers
                windowWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
                windowHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
        }       

        // for small pages with total height less then height of the viewport
        if(yScroll < windowHeight){
                pageHeight = windowHeight;
        } else { 
                pageHeight = yScroll;
        }

        // for small pages with total width less then width of the viewport
        if(xScroll < windowWidth){      
                pageWidth = windowWidth;
        } else {
                pageWidth = xScroll;
        }


        arrayPageSize = new Array(pageWidth,pageHeight,windowWidth,windowHeight) 
        return arrayPageSize;
}


//
// pause(numberMillis)
// Pauses code execution for specified time. Uses busy code, not good.
// Code from http://www.faqts.com/knowledge_base/view.phtml/aid/1602
//
function pause(numberMillis) {
        var now = new Date();
        var exitTime = now.getTime() + numberMillis;
        while (true) {
                now = new Date();
                if (now.getTime() > exitTime)
                        return;
        }
}

//
// getKey(key)
// Gets keycode. If 'x' is pressed then it hides the lightbox.
//

function getKey(e){
        if (e == null) { // ie
                keycode = event.keyCode;
        } else { // mozilla
                keycode = e.which;
        }
        key = String.fromCharCode(keycode).toLowerCase();

        if(key == 'x'){ hideLightbox(); }
}


//
// listenKey()
//
function listenKey () { document.onkeypress = getKey; }


//
// showLightbox()
// Preloads images. Pleaces new image in lightbox then centers and displays.
//
function showLightbox(objLink)
{
        // prep objects
        var objOverlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
        var objLightbox = document.getElementById('lightbox');
        var objCaption = document.getElementById('lightboxCaption');
        var objImage = document.getElementById('lightboxImage');
        var objLoadingImage = document.getElementById('loadingImage');
        var objLightboxDetails = document.getElementById('lightboxDetails');


        var arrayPageSize = getPageSize();
        var arrayPageScroll = getPageScroll();

        // center loadingImage if it exists
        if (objLoadingImage) {
                objLoadingImage.style.top = (arrayPageScroll[1] + ((arrayPageSize[3] - 35 - objLoadingImage.height) / 2) + 'px');
                objLoadingImage.style.left = (((arrayPageSize[0] - 20 - objLoadingImage.width) / 2) + 'px');
                objLoadingImage.style.display = 'block';
        }

        // set height of Overlay to take up whole page and show
        objOverlay.style.height = (arrayPageSize[1] + 'px');
        objOverlay.style.display = 'block';

        // preload image
        imgPreload = new Image();

        imgPreload.onload=function(){
                objImage.src = objLink.href;

                // center lightbox and make sure that the top and left values are not negative
                // and the image placed outside the viewport
                var lightboxTop = arrayPageScroll[1] + ((arrayPageSize[3] - 35 - imgPreload.height) / 2);
                var lightboxLeft = ((arrayPageSize[0] - 20 - imgPreload.width) / 2);

                objLightbox.style.top = (lightboxTop < 0) ? "0px" : lightboxTop + "px";
                objLightbox.style.left = (lightboxLeft < 0) ? "0px" : lightboxLeft + "px";


                objLightboxDetails.style.width = imgPreload.width + 'px';

                if(objLink.getAttribute('title')){
                        objCaption.style.display = 'block';
                        //objCaption.style.width = imgPreload.width + 'px';
                        objCaption.innerHTML = objLink.getAttribute('title');
                } else {
                        objCaption.style.display = 'none';
                }

                // A small pause between the image loading and displaying is required with IE,
                // this prevents the previous image displaying for a short burst causing flicker.
                if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE")!=-1){
                        pause(250);
                } 

                if (objLoadingImage) {  objLoadingImage.style.display = 'none'; }
                objLightbox.style.display = 'block';

                // After image is loaded, update the overlay height as the new image might have
                // increased the overall page height.
                arrayPageSize = getPageSize();
                objOverlay.style.height = (arrayPageSize[1] + 'px');

                // Check for 'x' keypress
                listenKey();

                return false;
        }

        imgPreload.src = objLink.href;

}





//
// hideLightbox()
//
function hideLightbox()
{
        // get objects
        objOverlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
        objLightbox = document.getElementById('lightbox');

        // hide lightbox and overlay
        objOverlay.style.display = 'none';
        objLightbox.style.display = 'none';

        // disable keypress listener
        document.onkeypress = '';
}




//
// initLightbox()
// Function runs on window load, going through link tags looking for rel="lightbox".
// These links receive onclick events that enable the lightbox display for their targets.
// The function also inserts html markup at the top of the page which will be used as a
// container for the overlay pattern and the inline image.
//
function initLightbox()
{

        if (!document.getElementsByTagName){ return; }
        var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

        // loop through all anchor tags
        for (var i=0; i<anchors.length; i++){
                var anchor = anchors[i];

                if (anchor.getAttribute("href") && (anchor.getAttribute("rel") == "lightbox")){
                        anchor.onclick = function () {showLightbox(this); return false;}
                }
        }

        // the rest of this code inserts html at the top of the page that looks like this:
        //
        // <div id="overlay">
        //              <a href="#" onclick="hideLightbox(); return false;"><img id="loadingImage" /></a>
        //      </div>
        // <div id="lightbox">
        //              <a href="#" onclick="hideLightbox(); return false;" title="Click anywhere to close image">
        //                      <img id="closeButton" />                
        //                      <img id="lightboxImage" />
        //              </a>
        //              <div id="lightboxDetails">
        //                      <div id="lightboxCaption"></div>
        //                      <div id="keyboardMsg"></div>
        //              </div>
        // </div>

        var objBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body").item(0);

        // create overlay div and hardcode some functional styles (aesthetic styles are in CSS file)
        var objOverlay = document.createElement("div");
        objOverlay.setAttribute('id','overlay');
        objOverlay.onclick = function () {hideLightbox(); return false;}
        objOverlay.style.display = 'none';
        objOverlay.style.position = 'absolute';
        objOverlay.style.top = '0';
        objOverlay.style.left = '0';
        objOverlay.style.zIndex = '90';
        objOverlay.style.width = '100%';
        objBody.insertBefore(objOverlay, objBody.firstChild);

        var arrayPageSize = getPageSize();
        var arrayPageScroll = getPageScroll();

        // preload and create loader image
        var imgPreloader = new Image();

        // if loader image found, create link to hide lightbox and create loadingimage
        imgPreloader.onload=function(){

                var objLoadingImageLink = document.createElement("a");
                objLoadingImageLink.setAttribute('href','#');
                objLoadingImageLink.onclick = function () {hideLightbox(); return false;}
                objOverlay.appendChild(objLoadingImageLink);

                var objLoadingImage = document.createElement("img");
                objLoadingImage.src = loadingImage;
                objLoadingImage.setAttribute('id','loadingImage');
                objLoadingImage.style.position = 'absolute';
                objLoadingImage.style.zIndex = '150';
                objLoadingImageLink.appendChild(objLoadingImage);

                imgPreloader.onload=function(){};       //      clear onLoad, as IE will flip out w/animated gifs

                return false;
        }

        imgPreloader.src = loadingImage;

        // create lightbox div, same note about styles as above
        var objLightbox = document.createElement("div");
        objLightbox.setAttribute('id','lightbox');
        objLightbox.style.display = 'none';
        objLightbox.style.position = 'absolute';
        objLightbox.style.zIndex = '100';       
        objBody.insertBefore(objLightbox, objOverlay.nextSibling);

        // create link
        var objLink = document.createElement("a");
        objLink.setAttribute('href','#');
        objLink.setAttribute('title','Click to close');
        objLink.onclick = function () {hideLightbox(); return false;}
        objLightbox.appendChild(objLink);

        // preload and create close button image
        var imgPreloadCloseButton = new Image();

        // if close button image found, 
        imgPreloadCloseButton.onload=function(){

                var objCloseButton = document.createElement("img");
                objCloseButton.src = closeButton;
                objCloseButton.setAttribute('id','closeButton');
                objCloseButton.style.position = 'absolute';
                objCloseButton.style.zIndex = '200';
                objLink.appendChild(objCloseButton);

                return false;
        }

        imgPreloadCloseButton.src = closeButton;

        // create image
        var objImage = document.createElement("img");
        objImage.setAttribute('id','lightboxImage');
        objLink.appendChild(objImage);

        // create details div, a container for the caption and keyboard message
        var objLightboxDetails = document.createElement("div");
        objLightboxDetails.setAttribute('id','lightboxDetails');
        objLightbox.appendChild(objLightboxDetails);

        // create caption
        var objCaption = document.createElement("div");
        objCaption.setAttribute('id','lightboxCaption');
        objCaption.style.display = 'none';
        objLightboxDetails.appendChild(objCaption);

        // create keyboard message
        var objKeyboardMsg = document.createElement("div");
        objKeyboardMsg.setAttribute('id','keyboardMsg');
        objKeyboardMsg.innerHTML = '(Click anywhere to close.)';
        objLightboxDetails.appendChild(objKeyboardMsg);


}




//
// addLoadEvent()
// Adds event to window.onload without overwriting currently assigned onload functions.
// Function found at Simon Willison's weblog - http://simon.incutio.com/
//
function addLoadEvent(func)
{       
        var oldonload = window.onload;
        if (typeof window.onload != 'function'){
        window.onload = func;
        } else {
                window.onload = function(){
                oldonload();
                func();
                }
        }

}



addLoadEvent(initLightbox);     // run initLightbox onLoad
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get value of the viewport and subtract 20 pixels from it. maybe wrap the image around a container and apply that value as the image's container's height and just set the image to height 100% so it scales.

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var imgHeight = windowHeight - 20;

$('.yourlightboximagecontainer').css('height',''+imgHeight+'px');
```

Html change:

```
<div class="yourlightboximagecontainer">
 <img src="yourlightboximage" />
</div>
```

then just css the image to fill 100% height of container. not sure if this would work on firefox tho as it handles image resizing differently.